# Como pegar o valor corrente de um select em uma row usando o evento click com o JS ou JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-eventos, jquery-select2

Dentro da div 'div-documentos' vou adicionando rows dinamicamente para documentos do usuário (CPF, CNPJ, etc.). Para o o select .sel-documento-tipo eu tenho um dois eventos: o Click (para eu armazenar o valor do select que estava selecionado originalmente pelo usuário) e o Change (para selecionar o valor do select que foi escolhido pelo usuário em seguida). O evento change, funciona perfeitamente, mas o evento evento click não está conseguindo pegar o valor do select. Será que é o bind que está atrapalhando? Ele pega o valor de outra linha, errado. Como eu pego o valor do select correto?

Abraço a todos!

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="div-documentos">
                <div class="form-group align-items-center row">
                    <div class="card card-shadow col-md-12 pl-0 pr-o pt-0 pb-0 border border-default">
                        <div class="card-block">

                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="form-group align-items-center">
                                <input class="hid-id" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Id" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Id" type="hidden" value="13">
                                <input class="hid-pessoaId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha uma Pessoa" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__PessoaId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].PessoaId" type="hidden" value="4">
                                <input class="hid-documento-tipo-descricao" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoDescricao" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoDescricao" type="hidden" value="TÍTULO DE ELEITOR">

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="control-label lb-documento-tipo" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId">Tipo de Documento</label>
                                    <select data-id="7" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control sel-documento-tipo select2-hidden-accessible" data-val="true" data-val-required="Escolha um Tipo de Documento" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoId" data-select2-id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"><option value=""></option><option value="1">CPF - CADASTRO NACIONAL DE PESSOA FÍSICA</option>
                                        <option value="3">RG - REGISTRO GERAL</option>
                                        <option value="4">RNE - REGISTRO NACIONAL DE ESTRANGEIROS</option>
                                        <option selected="selected" value="7" data-select2-id="2">TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</option>
                                        <option value="8">CTPS - CARTEIRA DE TRABALHO E PREVIDÊNCIA SOCIAL</option>
                                        <option value="9">CNH - CARTEIRA NACIONAL DE HABILITAÇÃO</option>
                                        <option value="10">CAM - CERTIFICADO DE ALISTAMENTO MILITAR</option>
                                        <option value="11">PASSAPORTE</option>
                                        <option value="12">NIS - NÚMERO DE IDENTIFICAÇÃO SOCIAL</option>
                                        </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="1" style="width: auto;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" title="Selecione uma opção" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__DocumentoTipoId-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="TÍTULO DE ELEITOR"><span class="select2-selection__clear" data-select2-id="3">×</span>TÍTULO DE ELEITOR</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
                                    <span class="text-danger val-documento-tipo field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].DocumentoTipoId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <label class="control-label lb-documento" for="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Documento">Núm. Documento</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control txt-documento" data-val="true" data-val-maxlength="O campo Documento deve ter no máximo 30 caracteres" data-val-maxlength-max="30" data-val-required="O campo Número do Documento é obrigatório" id="PessoaViewModel_PessoasDocumentosViewModel_0__Documento" name="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" value="12345">
                                    <span class="text-danger val-documento field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="PessoaViewModel.PessoasDocumentosViewModel[0].Documento" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-block">
                            <div class="card-actions float-right">
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-documento" title="Excluir Documento"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group align-items-center row">                     

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#div-documentos").on("change", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
    //Este evento já funciona

}).bind("click", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
    //Não estou conseguindo capturar o valor do select atual.
    var valorSelect = $(this).closest('.row').find('.sel-documento-tipo').val();
    alert(teste);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi porque você está utilizando o bind click. 
Só com o change não resolve seu problema?
Deste modo abaixo ele já não traz o valor do select?

```
$("#div-documentos").on("change", ".sel-documento-tipo", function (e) {
    var valorSelect = $(this).val();
    alert(valorSelect);
});
```

Abraço!

Comment: É que eu preciso capturar o valor do select ates de ele ser alteado novamente...